# I am unable to figure out a logic for summing up values in same column in r

Tags: r

Suppose you have a total spend of 180990.75 and a value of 9049.5375. In the column of spend, the first row of spend will be 9049.5375 and the second row will be 1st+1st and the third row will be 1st+2nd and this should run for 10 iterations. I want to replicate the  same thing in R
[image]

Comment: You can use `cumsum(df1$Spend)`

Comment: its not coming when i loop it for 10 times

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of your example data for testing

Comment: calc_spend_loop<-28046

  for (i in 1:10){
   
    
    new_rtable2$Spends[i]<-cumsum(new_rtable2$Spends[i]+calc_spend_loop)
  }



 new_rtable2$Spends
 [1] 28046 28046 28046 28046 28046 28046 28046 28046 28046 28046

Comment: you don't need a loop with `cumsum`.  What are the values of `Spends` column initially

Comment: But i need to make it go 10 times

Comment: you are not providing the dput of initial object.  So, it is not clear

Comment: The value of spends is null. formula is spends+calc_spend_loop

Comment: ok, sorry not clear.  you can use `dput(head(df1))` and the expected output

Comment: Browse[1]> dput(head(new_rtable2$Spends))
c(28046, 28046, 28046, 28046, 28046, 28046)

Comment: `cumsum(new_rtable$Spends)#
[1]  28046  56092  84138 112184 140230 168276`

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I run this for 10 times?

Comment: Not clear when you say 10 times.  Should that be recursive? then `for(i in 1:10) new_rtable$Spends <- cumsum(new_rtable$Spends)`

Comment: As of now its going 6 times([1]  28046  56092  84138 112184 140230 168276) but i want it to go for 10 times

Comment: But you have only 6 rows, right?

Comment: Yes. It's fine . Thank you so much :)